# bootstrap and jquery validate conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

My script tags are like so:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='validate/jquery.validate.js') }}"</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

it appears that between jquery validate, and bootstrap.js, only the last included lib works.
if i import as above, i can use validate but not bootstrap.
If i switch the last two, I can use bootstrap but not validate.
even weirder: jquery appears to work fine no matter the order.

What am i missing here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to close script tag

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='validate/jquery.validate.js') }}"></script>
                                                                          //^----- close this
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for intervening before i lost my marbles.

Answer (score 1):

a anglebracket is missing before `</script>` on second line.

```
.js') }}"</script>
```

should be

```
.js') }}"></script>
```